How To Get Last Exclusion on the Delete Event in VBA Access 365
I need to run a code every time I delete/add a record in the subform. I need to know the amount of records there are in the subform after delete/add event.
For instance. On the delete/add event, if there is one or more records, run code A. If there is no record, run code B.
I run DCount("tableName") to return the number of records from the subform source table.
The problem is that if I place this verification code in the Delete/AfterInsert events, the code runs for each record in the table. If there are seven records, the code will run seven times.
Code in the subform Delete event:
Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)
    If (DCount("*", "tblPermissoes") > 0) Then
        HideButton False
    Else
        HideButton True
    End If
End Sub

I need to hide/unhide a button, according to the amount of records of the subform. If there is record, unhide the button. otherwise, hide it.
I delete the subform's rows by selecting them with the mouse and pressing the delete button.


Simply use
Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)
    HideButton (RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0)
End Sub

The braces are not strictly necessary, but may be easier to read. The expression directly yields a Boolean that you can pass the subroutine. No need for If-Then-Else.

thanks for your reply. I'm already doing like you are suggesting. the problem is that it never shows RecordCount = 0. when the last record is deleted, RecordCount is equals to 1. then, the loop finishes on End Sub.

What happens if you place the the HideButton in the Form_AfterUpdate instead?

if I do the same for the Form_AfterUpdate event, just the insert action is captured. I delete the rows by selecting them and pressing the delete button. when I do this, nothing happens. I'm using the following code: Application.SetOption "Confirm Record Changes", 0, in order to turn off confirm "record changes".

when I insert some rows, by coping and pasting, AfterUpdate and AfterInsert events get trigged for each row. Current event is trigged just once at the end. when I delete all rows, Detete event get trigged for each row. Current event is trigged just once at the end. but, Current event is not always trigged.

if I have 4 rows, select and delete 2, for instance, Current gets trigged (one of the records become the current one). if I select all 4 rows (avoiding the new line) and press the delete button, Current get trigged also. if I select all 4 rows (including the new line) and press the delete button, Current DOESN'T get trigged.

What if instead of counting the records you tested the actual data. e.g. bind a TextBox to the Primary Key column (this TextBox can have Visible = False if you don't want to display it). If the PK is Not Null there is a Record. If it is Null there is no Record.

I had an idea similar to this one, slightly different. I'm going to check if Recordset.EOF is true. If yes, then the subform is empty. what do you think? I cannot try it now, unfortunately.

I have to deliver this software today. the way I found nearest to the ideal was to place HideButton function in the Form_Current event. it works in all situations exept when the user selects with the mouse ALL rows including the new record row and press the delete button. in this case, Form_Current event is not even trigged. as a way to work around that, I created a Clear List button.
